# How can I highlight the purchase orders in same state differently for users to indicate the approval action?

Tags: openerp-7

In the workflow, there are multiple users to approve the purchase quotations, which is in the same draft state. Color attribute can be used to highlight, based on states, but since this is in the same state, how can I trigger the user attention to approve new quotations.

For example, user1 creates the quotation, user2 receives it (highlighted)and approved (color changing to grey), user3 receive it (highlighted) and approved (grey). In all these, state is same draft state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a functional field, which evaluates based on User, use this field in Tree View for and set Color attributes based on value of it...